# How to condition the translation in routing using i18n?

Tags: angular

## How to condition the translation in routing using i18n

Here is how i did :

```
//in angular.json
   "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale":"en",
        "locales": {
          "fr":"src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"
        }
      },

    .............
    "fr": {
              "localize": ["fr"]
            },
```

And i have 2 files : messages.xlf ( the default one ) and messages.fr.xlf fro french translations

I want to switch languages manually in the interface

First of all i translated in terminal using this command

```
ng serve --configuration=fr
```

this works as expected

But i want to know if there is way to do it in the interface not in the terminal because the user can't use terminal

I did this :

Here's the template:

```
   <select class="form-select" i18n aria-label="Default select example" #lang            (change)="onLanguageChange(lang.value)">
                    <option selected value="en-US"> 
                        English
                    </option>
                    <option value="fr">French</option>
    </select>
```

And here's the component:

```
//And component
 onLanguageChange(selectedLanguage: string) {
        console.log('The selected language is: ',selectedLanguage);
        
        if (selectedLanguage === 'fr') {
          this.router.navigate(['/fr']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/en-US']);
        }
      }
```

I want to know how to implement this: By deault the language is '/en' and i want that a user switch to 'fr' it should call the french translation file ( 'src/locale/messages.fr.xlf ' )

In simple terms, i want to know how can i conditionally calls the translations files

Please help me if you have any ideas of this, THANK YOU !

Comment: When you [deploy multiple locales](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy#deploy-multiple-locales) using Angular really you're creating different apps, so your select should redirect to a new direction (using javascript [windows.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Another option is use libraries like ngx-translate or transcolo that allow you to have an **unique** aplication.

Comment: Thanks ! lemme try transcolo to if it can work? does it work together with i18n ??

Comment: Sorry, I'm very newbie in transcolo, you can check the [docs](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/)

Comment: Finally, i found out that i18n ( supported by ng/localize ) does not offer a runtime translation, it offers a compile time translation, means that it is not possible to switch to different languages with i18n without reloading the page, the translation is done while compilation, For more details you can visit this ressource :  https://phrase.com/blog/posts/best-libraries-for-angular-i18n/                                                                                                     Thank you for your reactions